# Python url template tags giving only part of a absolute url.. ..Must be a lack of sleep

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I must be suffering from a serious lack of sleep but I am stumped.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the `{% url %}` directive to give me the right url.  So let's start with the basics..

urls.py

```
from people.views import employee_detail

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r'/uid/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', employee_detail, {'template_name' : 'people/single.html'}, name = 'employee_view'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_list_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from people.models import Employee, OfficeLocation

def employee_detail(request, id, template_name = None):
    """
        This will give you a full detailed information on a user
        based off of there name.
    """
    person = Employee.objects.get(id = id)        
    return render_to_response(template_name, _getDetail(person),
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Lastly here is a sample snippet of my `people/single.html`.

people/single.html

`<tr>

    <td width="300px">Supervisor: <a href="{% url employee_view , id=supervisor_id %}">{{ supervisor }}</a></td>
</tr>`

Now I can see that I am passing the right data back and forth.  For example this results
in a link which in the code looks like

`<td width="300px">Supervisor: <a href="//uid/415/">NAME</a></td>`

Now what am I doing wrong..  I'm missing the hostname part of the url..  **Can someone please tell me how to get back "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uid/415" or whatever the hostname is?**

*Grr..  It's got to be simple I know I'm suffering from a lac of sleep..*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[get_absolute_url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) is a misnomer, and never returns an absolute (scheme + hostname + port) part. For that aspect of things, you need to use the [Sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/sites/) (using [Site.objects.get_current()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls)) and get the domain, etc separately.

The naming of the method has raised enough eyebrows that [Simon Willison has proposed replacing it entirely](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ReplacingGetAbsoluteUrl).

Comment: So I broke down and used the Sites framework.  Once I work through it I'll give you credit.  Thanks!!